# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The Workbook already contains a sheet of this name (after upgrading java 1.6 to 1.8)

Tags: java

I have recently upgraded my java version from 1.6 to 1.8 and i am started getting error as "The Workbook already contains a sheet of this name" which used under poi-ooxml-3.9.jar

```
SXSSFWorkbook workbooks=new SXSSWorkbook();

public Sheet createSheet(String workbookId,string name){
   return workbooks.createSheet(name);
}
```

Same is working fin on version java 1.6 without any error.

Comment: What's your input for the sheetname?

Comment: i am passing String name="Market_Sheet"

Comment: Try using workbooks.createSheet(WorkbookUtil.createSafeSheetName(name));

Comment: It runs successfully but when i run twice or thrice i get the same error , this error is coming on unpredictable number of runs. :(

Comment: That makes sense? You can't have two sheets with the same name, try using different names for the sheets.

Comment: Thanks a lot , yes it runs as it expected. :)